# "I'm done with my coding" from Agile perspective

Tags: testing, agile, coding

**Scenario:** I'm working in an Agile environment. The dev environment has not been configured yet, and I'm told to code a piece of an application.

I code the module and write appropriate unit tests for it as part of the coding task, and test the code offline in my own box.

There is also a testing task that needs to be performed by a non-technical testing person.

**Questions:**

1. At this point can I claim that I'm done with coding, since I haven't really tested my code even in the dev environment?
2. Can I move my development task to "DONE", or do I need to move it to "BLOCKED" due to the lack of an environment?

Comment: What is **_your team's_** procedure?  It doesn't matter what people answer here.  What matters is how your team has agreed to operate.

Comment: Also consider "working software."

Comment: I do like @MetaFight's answer, but I would just add that "done with my coding" also implies that the code is being thrown over the wall to testing never to be thought of again. The coding is probably not done once it goes to testing as it may come back with defects. Agile / XP promote communication with all the people involved and testers are people too.

Comment: @Encaitar no, this would just be the scrum team testing. So it'd definitely come right back at devs for fixing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only your team can decide whether you've reached your definition of **DONE**.

If this were my team I would be tempted to declare the task as **BLOCKED** but, maybe I don't have all the information.  Maybe your scenario is unique somehow and your task can be considered finished.

My point is that we don't know enough about your team, project, infrastructure, office politics, etc, to give you a meaningful answer.

That's why teams typically make their own "Definition of Done" that best meets **their** needs.

Answer (score 1):

> The dev environment has not been configured yet

Sounds like a Technical Task got missed in Sprint Zero.

> I code ... write appropriate unit tests ... test the code offline in my own box.

So you *have* done some Unit Testing.

Since your team has a separate "User Testing" process on your way to "Done", then your code should normally become "Ready to Test" at this point.

However, given that you have *no way* for that testing to occur (no environment), then it *has* to be marked as "Blocked", which should prompt your Scrum Master to leap into action and get the problem resolved.